# Java- Creating an Ackermann Value graph

Tags: java, ackermann

I am asked by my teacher to edit this graph code. The graph is already made. what he wants me to do is to adjusted the code so it graphs rescursive ackermann values. so if put m = 3 and n = 2 it graphs it. How do i adjust my ackermann method? Any suggestions?

```
import java.awt.Color;
        import java.awt.Container;
        import java.awt.Dimension;
        import java.awt.Font;
        import java.awt.Graphics;
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
        import javax.swing.JApplet;
        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.JTextField;
        public class ArckermannGraph extends JApplet implements ActionListener {



            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private static int temp;
            private static int count;
            private static int countTotal = 0;
            int forColor = 1;
            int m, n;
            boolean paint = false;
            Font titleFont;
            Font regularFont;
            //*** two buttons are declared
            JButton DrawLinesButton;
            JButton clearLinesButton;

            //*** two input values declared
            JTextField inputLineNumber1;
            JTextField inputLineNumber2;

            Container contentPane;
            //*** all JApplet have a method paint to draw the graphics
            //*** Graphics object is brought in
            //*** paint() is automatically called
            public void paint (Graphics page)
            {
                if(!paint)
                    graphInitialize(page);
                super.paint(page);
                setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                graph(page);

            }
            //*** The Applet class defines a method that is essential for programming applets, 
            //*** the init() method. This method is called just after the applet object has 
            //*** been created and before it appears on the screen. Its purpose is to give
            //*** the applet a chance to do any necessary initialization. This method is
            //*** called by the system, not by your program. Your job as a programmer 
            //*** is just to provide a definition of the init() method. 
            public void init()
            {
                System.out.println("init has been called");
                contentPane = getContentPane();
                contentPane.setLayout(null);
                //*** 32 and 18 are pixel size
                titleFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 32);
                regularFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18);

                //*** memory is allocated for Button
                DrawLinesButton = new JButton("Draw Lines");
                //*** this button is active and will be read
                //*** by method actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                DrawLinesButton.addActionListener(this);
                //*** Location of button is created 
                DrawLinesButton.setBounds(350,550,150,40);

                //*** memory is allocated for Button
                clearLinesButton = new JButton("Clear Lines");
                //*** this button is active and will be read
                //*** by method actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                clearLinesButton.addActionListener(this);
                //*** Location of button is created 
                clearLinesButton.setBounds(350,600,150,40);

                //*** setBounds() creates the input box
                //*** memory is allocated for TextField
                inputLineNumber1 = new JTextField(15);
                //*** Location of TextField is created 
                inputLineNumber1.setBounds(210,560,50,30);

                //*** memory is allocated for TextField
                inputLineNumber2 = new JTextField(15);
                //*** Location of TextField is created 
                inputLineNumber2.setBounds(210,590,50,30);

                //*** add them to contentPane
                contentPane.add(DrawLinesButton);
                contentPane.add(clearLinesButton);
                contentPane.add(inputLineNumber1);
                contentPane.add(inputLineNumber2);
            }
            public void graphInitialize (Graphics page)
            {
                Graphics g = getGraphics(); 
                Color c = getBackground(); 
                g.setColor(c); 
                for(int x=0;x<1250;x++)
                    g.drawLine (x,900, x,0);
                System.out.println("graphInitialize has been called");
                page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                page.setFont(titleFont);
                page.setFont(regularFont);
                //*** Strings line up with setBounds for each JTextField
            //  page.drawString("Enter line number 1: ",40, 580);
            //  page.drawString("Enter line number 2: ",40, 610);
                //*** initialize input to 0
                inputLineNumber1.setText("0");
                inputLineNumber2.setText("0");
            }
            public void graph(Graphics page)
            {
                System.out.println("graph has been called");
                if(!inputLineNumber1.getText().equals("")&&!inputLineNumber2.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    //*** text must be changed to int using the wrapper class Integer
                    int lineNumber1 = Integer.parseInt(inputLineNumber1.getText());
                    int lineNumber2 = Integer.parseInt(inputLineNumber2.getText());


                    //*** method called here
                    int result = drawLines(lineNumber1, lineNumber2, page);
                    //*** method called here

                    //*** 3 strings are placed in the window
                    page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    page.setFont(titleFont);
                    page.drawString("Practice Graph", 540, 50);
                    page.setFont(regularFont);
                    page.drawString("Number of lines:  " + result, 600, 580);
                    page.drawString("Value of lines again:  " + result, 600, 610);
                    page.drawString("Enter line number 1: ",40, 580);
                    page.drawString("Enter line number 2: ",40, 610);
                }
            }

            private int drawLines(int lineNumber1, int lineNumber2, Graphics page) 
            {   //*********************************************************
                //*** this method could be the recursive Ackermann function
                //*********************************************************
                count = 200;
                countTotal = 0;
                setNewColor(page,(int) (Math.random() * 12)+1);
                for(int i=0;i<lineNumber1;i++)
                {
                    page.drawLine (count,500, count,400);
                    count++;
                    countTotal++;
                }
                setNewColor(page,(int) (Math.random() * 12)+1);
                for(int i=0;i<lineNumber2;i++)
                {
                    page.drawLine (count,500, count,300);
                    count++;
                    countTotal++;
                }
                return countTotal;
            }

            private void setNewColor(Graphics page, int forColor)
            {
                switch (forColor)
                {
                case 1:
                    page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    page.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    page.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    page.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    page.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    page.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    page.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    page.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    page.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    page.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                    break;
                case 11:
                    page.setColor(Color.PINK);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    page.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;
                }
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //*** buttons are active
                String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
                //*** one of two possible values of actionCommand
                if (actionCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("Draw Lines"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Draw Lines has been called");
                    paint = true;
                    countTotal = 0;
                    count = 0;
                    repaint();//*** method paint() is called again
                }
                else if (actionCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("Clear Lines"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Clear Lines has been called");
                    this.clear();
                    inputLineNumber1.setText("");
                    inputLineNumber2.setText("");
                }
            }

            public void clear() 
            { 
                //*** Graphics object is gotten
                Graphics g = getGraphics(); 
                Color c = getBackground(); 
                g.setColor(c); 
                //*** lines of the background color cover up the image
                for(int i=100;i<1250;i++)
                    g.drawLine (i,500, i,150);
                for(int i=600;i<1000;i++)
                    g.drawLine (i,700, i,75);

            }
            private  static int ackermann(int M,int N){
                int value = 0;
                if(M == 0){
                    value = N+1;


                }else
                    if(N == 0){
                        value = ackermann(M-1,1);
                    }else

                        value = ackermann(M-1,ackermann(M,N-1)) ;
                        return value;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210615/plotting-a-graph-using-java-applet